# Autofilling polygon with semi-regular spaced points

Tags: qgis, point, line, point-in-polygon, fill

I'm looking to fill a polygon with points with a regular spacing, but the points don't need to be in line vertically.

In the image below, the points are all spaced out evenly on an x/y spacing, but while the rows are all in line, they have been shifted left or right to match the polygon shape and fit in the maximum points on each horizontal row.

[image: Example of how the output should look]

This was done on another piece of software, which we no longer have access to, but I'm looking to do the same in QGIS.

Any ideas?

With @Babel's help, I'm able to get somewhere, but where two polygons meet there is an overlap, the intersection expression worked for displaying the lines but not in the 'geometry by expression' output.

I would like to keep the lines within their own polygon, rather than the overlap.

[image: overlapping lines]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create parallel lines with Geometry generator (or geometry by expression, [see here for the difference](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)) and intersect them with the polygon. Than style this lines with `Marker Line` symbology. This is for visualization purposes; if you need actual geometries, it works very similarly, but with a few differences, see below.

**For visualization purposes**

To get horizontal lines, simple create the bounding box of the polygon and create a line from the upper left to the upper right angle of this bounding box, than shift this line in parallel several times for a defined interval - `70` [meters] in my case: you can change this value on line 8:

```
intersection( 
    $geometry,
    collect_geometries (
        array_foreach (
            generate_series (
                0,  
                bounds_height( $geometry), 
                70
            ),
            offset_curve( 
                make_line (
                    make_point (
                        x_min (bounds($geometry)),
                        y_max (bounds($geometry))),
                    make_point (
                        x_max (bounds($geometry)),
                        y_max (bounds($geometry)))
                ),
                -@element
            )
        )
    )
)
```

*Screenshot 1: the undelying dotted lines are here for visualization purposes only (I added an additional symbol layer):*
[image]

*Screenshot 2: Setting `Marker Line` with interval (one point every 100 m) and offset (first point 20 m from the polygon boundary on the left side):*

[image]

**To create actual geometries**

If you have several polygons where the lines created in step 1 intersect with more than one polygon, see below how to solve this (it's based on this here, but with some other workflow except step 1 and 4 from here).

In principle, to create actual geometries, it works very similar as the solution above for visual purposes only:

1. Use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / [Geometry by expression][1]` with the same expression as above, but only starting from line 3 (`collect_geometries (` and deleting the closing bracket `)` on the last line. This creats lines that project beyond the polygon.
2. Use Menu  Vector / Geoprocessing tools / Clip`, set the line from step 1 as input and the polygon as` Overlay layer`. You get lines clipped to the polygon.
3. All lines are part of one multipart geometry, but we want a single feature per line, thus use `Menu Vector / Geometry Tools / Multipart to singleparts`.
4. Use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Points along geometry`, where you can define the `Distance` and `Start offset` for the points to be generated.

[image]

**To avoid overlapping of the lines with neighboring polygons**

Preparation: be sure you polygon layer contains an attribute with a field containing a unique identifier (field `id` in my case).

1. Step 1 as above (Geometry by expression), result:

   [image]
2. Run `Menu Vector / Geoprocessing Tools / Clip`, set the lines created in step 1 as `Input layer` and the polygon layer as `Overlay layer`, result:

   [image]
3. On the lines created in step 2, run `Menu Vector / Geometry Tools / Multipart to singleparts` - output visually looks the same as above.
4. Nex click the icon `Select by expression`, paste the following expression an apply it to select all lines (highlighted in yellow in the next screenshot) that can be deleted. Replace `'polygon'` with the name of your polygon layer and `id` with the name of your attribute field containing the unique identifier:

   ```
   disjoint(
   $geometry,
   with_variable (
      'current',
      id,
      aggregate( 
          'polygon', 
          'collect', 
          $geometry, 
          filter:=id=@current
      )
   )
   )
   ```

   [image]
5. Toggle editing and delete the selected lines.

   [image]
6. Continue with step 4 from the previous solution above: `Points along geometry` - see result:

   [image]

<strike>**Old solution, still preserved in case it's useful for others**</strike>

This is an option to create not horizontal lines, but lines parallel to one of the polygon boundary segments.

As you don't provide more details, I show how I did it: adapt this to your use case (details below). Create a new symbol layer on the polygon layer, set it to `Geometry Generator / LineString` and paste this expression. Style the lines thus created as `Marker Line`:

```
intersection( 
    $geometry,
    collect_geometries (
        array_foreach (
            generate_series (1, 5000, 70),
            offset_curve( 
                extend (
                    make_line (
                        point_n( $geometry,2),
                        point_n( $geometry,1)
                    ),
                    1000,
                    0
                )
                ,
                -@element
            )
        )
    )
)
```

*Screenshot: the undelying dotted lines are here for visualization purposes only (I added an additional symbol layer):*
[image]

**How you can adapt this to your use case:**

1. The direction of the line. I took a line parallel to the upper polygon boundary. The upper right vertex of the polygon has index-no. 1, the upper left one is no. 2. So on line 9 and 10, change the index-no of the vertices that form the line to which your lines should be parallel.
2. The interval between and number of parallel lines are defined in line 5 inside `generate_series()`. In my case, it generates parallel lines with interval of `70` [meters], starting from `1` to `5000`. Increase this last value to get more lines, increase `70` to get more distance between the lines.
3. The lines normally must be extended to cover the whole polygon. This is done with the values in line 12 and 13, `1000` and `0` in my case. You can safely increase these values as much as you want as the lines anyhow will be "cut" to the polygon extent by the `intersection()` function (line 1).
4. In line 16, you have the variable `@element`, refering to the current iteration of the array created in line 5 (the `generate_series()` part). Depending to which side of the line you want to create parallel copies, this value must be positive (shifting to the left of the line, than delete the minus sign: `-`) or negative (as in my example, than the line is shifted to the right).